# antd form and next js generating TypeError: window.setTimeout is not a function error

Tags: reactjs, forms, next.js, antd

i am new to next js and I was trying to create a form with antd component library when i faced this error. The page renders correctly when i exclude the  tag. But I couldn't get it to work with a complete form setup.
What am I doing wrong?

```
 <Form size='large'   
 labelCol={{ span: 4 }}
wrapperCol={{ span: 9 }}
>

<Form.Item>
<Space>
<Form.Item
    rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Missing first name' }]}
>
  <Input placeholder="First Name" />
</Form.Item>

<Form.Item
 
  rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Missing last name' }]}
>
<Input placeholder="Last Name" />
</Form.Item>
</Space>
</Form.Item>
   <Form.Item
 
 rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Missing Phone Number' }]}
>
 <Input placeholder="Phone Number" />
</Form.Item>



</Form>
```

the error generated is the following

```
Server Error
TypeError: window.setTimeout is not a function

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
FormStore.warningUnhooked
file:///D:/School%20Management/School%20Management/node_modules/rc-field-form/lib/useForm.js (127:32)
FormStore.getFieldsValue
file:///D:/School%20Management/School%20Management/node_modules/rc-field-form/lib/useForm.js (183:11)
Field._this.getValue
file:///D:/School%20Management/School%20Management/node_modules/rc-field-form/lib/Field.js (393:48)
Field._this.getControlled
file:///D:/School%20Management/School%20Management/node_modules/rc-field-form/lib/Field.js (416:25)
Field._this.getOnlyChild
file:///D:/School%20Management/School%20Management/node_modules/rc-field-form/lib/Field.js (366:110)
Field.render
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `window.setTimeout` isn't supported on the server where there is no window. One of your included packages probably doesn't support SSR.

Comment: This is supposedly fix in newer version of the package provided by the stack trace: https://github.com/react-component/field-form/issues/191 and https://github.com/react-component/field-form/pull/144